# Access default_url_options from rake task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `application.rb` file I have a few options to modify my apps URLs like so:

`config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }`

But these do not seem to take effect in my Rake tasks, despite the fact that I am running them in the Rails environment via the `:environment` dependency.

I know that I can get this to work simply by calling the following in my rake task:

`default_url_options[:trailing_slash] = true`

... but I'd like to DRY this up. Is there a clean way to make a rake task use Rails' `default_url_options` from `application.rb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following in a `rake` task (and in Rails `console`):

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_url_options
```

Comment: I ended up using this:     default_url_options.merge!(Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_url_options)
Thanks!